# arg(1) changed when doing AJAX

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I created a custom module named my_module.

In `hook_menu()` I define the following path.

```
$items['my-module/item'] = array(
  'title' => 'Item',
  'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
  'page arguments' => array('my_module_item_form'),
  'access arguments' => array('access item content'),
);
```

This is the code for `my_module_item_form()`.

```
$arg = arg(1); // Problem here! Should return "item", right?
...
// $form[...] = array('#ajax' => ...);

$form['arg'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden',
  '#value' => $arg,
  // I also tried '#default_value'
)

// Submit field
```

Basically, I really need to obtain `item` in `arg(1)` and nothing else.

When I edit fields (not fields with ajax) and click submit, I can obtain the correct `arg(1)` in my `hook_submit` which is `"item"`. Now, when I edit fields with ajax and click submit, `arg(1)` returns `"ajax"` which I do not like.

How should I obtain `"item"` in `arg(1)` in in the form submission handler during an ajax call in my form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When implementing AJAX in a form, it will send a callback to system/ajax, if you didn't set your path in the AJAX properties. So, when you use `arg(1)` in your code, it will return *ajax*, which is the value assigned to the hidden form field.

Comment: What is the workaround to my problem?

Comment: Could you share your complete code?

Comment: @NeigylR.Noval There isn't a workaround; even if you would set  [#ajax\['path'\]](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax_path), the path would change, and `arg(1)` would return a value different from the one you are expecting.