# arg() dependent hidden field in AJAX form

Tags: forms, ajax, files

Basically, I have a hidden field I set using `arg()`.

```
$form['slideid'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden',
  '#value' => arg(2)
);

$form['fid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => t('Image'),
    '#default_value' => "",
    '#size' => 40,
    '#description' => t("Image should be less than xxxxxxxxxxxx."),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="things">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

This value is set correctly once the form loads, but after a call to a AJAX field (managed_file), the form is refreshed and I get the wrong value in `arg(2)`.

I have found [arg(1) changed when doing AJAX](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/71408/arg1-changed-when-doing-ajax-in-hook-form), which doesn't give me any solution.

Is there any alternative that can be used, or can we skip the hidden field in the AJAX re-build? Is it possible to use a managed_file element without the AJAX submit?

Comment: Are you implementing a new content type, or are you simply building a form?

Comment: actually the hook_form is being used for a Custom Entity...

Comment: That is because the form is rebuilt from the Ajax path, which in this case, `systen/ajax`. You can store the slide ID in form_state, and check if it exists before overwriting (if it is already set, do not overwrite which means the form is rebuilt from Ajax callback).

Comment: `hook_form()` is the hook used by Drupal for content type, which means it is implemented from a module that creates a new content type (for example, the  Blog or the Forum module). In the other cases, you are not implementing `hook_form()`, but you are simply writing a form builder: a function that build a form using the form element provided from the form API.

Comment: I am explaining this because many users confuse the two concepts, which are completely different. In fact, the parameters provided to [`hook_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_form/7) are totally different from the parameters provided to a form builder, or other hooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @AyeshK, I checked the `$form_state` in the `hook_form` before i set the value from arg()

```
 $form['slideid'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden',
  '#value' => (!empty($form_state['input']['slideid']) ? $form_state['input']['slideid'] : arg(2))
);
```

This could also be done in the `hook_form_submit` ...

```
function hook_form_submit($form, &$form_state){

    if($form_state['values']['slideid'] != $form_state['input']['slideid']){
        $form_state['values']['slideid'] = (int)$form_state['input']['slideid'];
    }
   //====save the form data...

}
```

It looks like a crude fix, but it works for me.

Thank you for your help @AyeshK & @kiamlaluno

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ajax submit you need to set callback path using [#ajax['path']](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax_path) otherwise it will automatically set to **system/ajax**.